# How to get rid of index columns and start writing defined header in first column

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

The output in excel looks like this:

[image]

So now I simply want to get rid of index column and modify header format. 
For that I'll use parameters:

```
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',startrow=1, header=False,index=False)
```

and Now:

```
# Write the column headers with the defined format.
for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
    worksheet.write(0, col_num + 1, value, header_format)
```

But the output looks incorrect:

So what would be the way to fix it?

[image]

The whole code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1':['Roman','Nick','Jarrod','Spencer','Sasha'],
                   'Column2':['Red','Blue','Green','Yellow','Orange']})


writer = ExcelWriter('TestFile.xlsx')

df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',startrow=1, header=False,index=False)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
# Add a header format.
header_format = workbook.add_format({
    'bold': True,
    'text_wrap': False,
    'valign': 'top',
    'fg_color': '#D7E4BC',
    'border': 1})
# Write the column headers with the defined format.
for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
    worksheet.write(0, col_num + 1, value, header_format)
# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column index is off by 1. Use:

```
worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)
```

Instead of:

```
worksheet.write(0, col_num + 1, value, header_format)
```

Comment: Oh! That was easy! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work:

```
import csv
df.to_excel(filename,index=False)
```